# Moving/Adding Additional Swap Location - Redhat 5

Tags: linux, redhat, memory, disk-space-utilization, swap

OK, here's what's going on.

I've got a RedHat 5 server with a swap partition (/dev/sda3) that's 3GB.

For some reason swap memory is still being taken up on / (/dev/sda2), and fills up the drive on occasion. Is there a way I can tell my system that if it needs to use HD space for swap, to use a different drive?

Comment: Are you sure that _swap_ is filling up `/`, and not temporary files (or log files, or something else)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find really what is using your space, use `df` to see the partition layout and disk usage, and `du / -h --max-depth=1` to get an estimative of directory sizes and from that see what is happening.

Also, `swapon -s` will show exactly what swap devices are being used and how much of each one is occupied.

Comment: I've done searches for large files, tmp files, and even moved some larger stuff off the partition to another one. Space keeps filling up. After a fresh reboot I get the space back, then it fills up again eventually.

Comment: @rkalajian That sounds like `/tmp` or some kind of logfile, not `swap`. Do you have `tmpfs` or `ramfs`? Add the output of your `df` to your question.

Comment: @coredump Logs are on a seperate partition, and /tmp is clean. 'df' shows: 

/dev/sda2,2972268,1933592,885256,69% / - 
/dev/sda,131581128,33872852,90916400,28%,r5 -
/dev/sdb1,481711200,142404696,314442304,32%,/data2 - 
tmpfs,4155412,0,4155412,0%,/dev/shm

Comment: Yeah that output shows nothing really wrong. See if `free` is showing your swap enabled.

Comment: It does. It's pretty empty right now, with most of the 3GB free.

Comment: You can also use files; you don't have to use partitions, and you don't have to use something like `swapd` to do so.

Comment: @mattdm hmm you're correct, it slipped my mind on the first answer. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring all the parts of your question that make no sense, you can use `mkswap` to format a device to use as swap, and you can use `swapon` to activate it. Add it to `/etc/fstab` if you want to make it permanent.

Comment: I've already got a swap device, and no means to add a new device for additional swap space right now. I'm looking into creating a swap file on an additional partition, but I need to know it'll take precedence over filling up / when the actual swap drive overflows.

Comment: @rkalajian — look at `man swapon` for how to set the relative priority of your swap devices. (This can go in fstab, too.)

Comment: @mattdm - That sounds like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow the below steps to create a additional swap partition on Linux.

- Just create a partition with `fdisk` command and change it's partition code for Linux swap partition e.g. `82`.
- now use command `mkswap drive_name` to create the swap signature, then use `swapon drive name` command to activate the swap partition.

For example, to create swap partition type:

```
mkswap /dev/sdb1
```

and to activate it

```
swapon /dev/sdb1
```

Note : I have mentioned `/dev/sdb1` for example purposes, you use the drive as per your scenario.

now mount the created swap partition on `/etc/fstab` file.

for testing you can use below commands :-

`swapon -s` shows swap usage summary by device

`free -m` Display amount of free and used memory in the system